# Modal window error

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am a beginner in `CSS` and would like to know how I can put the background of this modal always occupying 100% of the page and even if the page is zoomed in, the background will still occupy 100% of the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();

  var id = $(this).attr("href");

  var alturaTela = $(document).height();
  var larguraTela = $(window).width();

  //colocando o fundo preto
  $('#mascara').css({'width':larguraTela,'height':alturaTela});
  $('#mascara').fadeIn(1000); 
  $('#mascara').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

  var left = ($(window).width() /2) - ( $(id).width() / 2 );
  var top = ($(window).height() / 2) - ( $(id).height() / 2 );
  
  $(id).css({'top':top,'left':left});
  $(id).show(); 
  });

  $("#mascara").click( function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(".window").hide();
  });

  $('.fechar').click(function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  $("#mascara").hide();
  $(".window").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.window {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  z-index: 9900;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#mascara {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
}
.fechar {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#modalAdocao" rel ="modal">Janela 2 modal</a>
<div class="window" id="modalAdocao">
  <button class="fechar">Fechar</button>
  <h4>Formulario</h4>
  <form action="#" method="post">
<label for="nome">Nome:</label>
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
<br />
<label for="nome">Senha:</label>
<input type="text" name="senha" id="senha">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
  </form>
</div>

<!-- mascara para cobrir o site -->
<div id="mascara"></div>
```

Comment: thats a background layer and cover the full width and height of the screen, what you want? want to remove that layer?

Comment: Thats background layer must cover the full width and height of the screen

Comment: as per your code, its covering the full width and height, whats the issue?

Comment: Your English is difficult to understand :(

What I would like to do is ensure that the background fade of the modal window always occupies 100% of the length and height and that this ratio never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will helps.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Janela modal</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();

                var id = $(this).attr("href");
                $('#mascara').fadeIn(1000); 
                $('#mascara').fadeTo("slow",0.8);
                $(id).show();   
            });

            $("#mascara").click( function(){
                $(this).hide();
                $(".window").hide();
            });

            $('.fechar').click(function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();
                $("#mascara").hide();
                $(".window").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

    .window{
        display:none;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:50%;
        right: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        margin: auto;
        background:#FFF;
        z-index:9900;
        padding:10px;
        border-radius:10px;
    }

    #mascara{
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index:9000;
        background-color:#000;
        display:none;
    }

    .fechar{display:block; text-align:right;}

    </style>

</head>


<body>

    <a href="#modalAdocao" rel  ="modal">Janela 2 modal</a>




    <div class="window" id="modalAdocao">
        <button class="fechar">Fechar</button>
        <h4>Formulario</h4>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
            <br />

            <label for="nome">Senha:</label>
            <input type="text" name="senha" id="senha">
            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="enviar">

        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- mascara para cobrir o site --> 
    <div id="mascara"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's help!

Comment: Height and width attributes can be given in% rather than px?

Comment: We can give width and height in % for model box. Height will be adjusted with content of model box.